# (html) How do I hide my navbar when my website is viewed on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, navbar

Is there a way to do this with html and css or can I only do it with javascript/bootstrap? I'm fairly new to coding so detailed explanations if possible would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

There several approaches to do that

1. Detect device is touchable (e.g. with Modernizr like tools) - I do not recommend, cause nowadays event laptops provided with touch displays.
2. By device's viewport - here's the good [table list](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/target/using/experiences/vec/mobile-viewports.html) with most popular devices viewports by Adobe

I prefer second approach

So the solution comes in hand with [CSS media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

And read about [mobile first](https://medium.com/@Vincentxia77/what-is-mobile-first-design-why-its-important-how-to-make-it-7d3cf2e29d00) techniques

Example (press the `Full page` button after running snippet to look how it's gonna look in desktops)

```css
<style>
  #navbar {
    display: none;
  }

  @media (min-width: 640px) {
    #navbar {
      background: lightblue;
      height: 60px;
    }
  }

  main {
    background: #ccc;
    min-height: 40vh;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<div id="navbar"></div>
<main></main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with css media query. If you are begineer here is a small tutorial on that [CSS media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

According to mobile device size you can hide the navbar.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar{
      display:none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide show with the help of @media screen to show or hide the code in different devices sizes.

Examples:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .hide_on_mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .hide_on_mobile {
    display: block;
  }
}
```